# Widget not reponding because of Geocoder

Tags: android, geocoding

I have developed a widget to find the weather. It works perfectly but after a certain update interval it crashes and stops responding (click events not working) automatically after few minutes/hours. It throws the following error in logcat.

```
04-11 10:40:17.004: D/androidNetworkLocationListeners(24325): Still have listener com.google.android.location.internal.client.NetworkLocationClient$1@413d9070
04-11 10:40:17.007: D/androidNetworkLocationListeners(24325): Still have listener com.google.android.location.internal.client.NetworkLocationClient$1@413d9070
04-11 10:40:17.011: D/WifiLocator(24325): Too many no-location APs. Will not compute a location nor go to the server. hasLocation=0 noLocation=0 cacheMiss=0
04-11 10:40:17.019: E/GPS(135): [gps_inject_location][line = 721] : Failed with GPS driver is not initialized
04-11 10:40:17.027: D/WifiLocator(24325): Too many no-location APs. Will not compute a location nor go to the server. hasLocation=0 noLocation=0 cacheMiss=0
04-11 10:40:17.043: E/GPS(135): [gps_inject_location][line = 721] : Failed with GPS driver is not initialized
04-11 10:40:17.125: I/System.out(24325): [INFO:3211479]: LogSource: Running flush
04-11 10:40:20.812: I/System.out(24325): [INFO:3215167]: LogSource: Running delayed flush
04-11 10:40:20.824: I/System.out(24325): [INFO:3215181]: LogSource: Running flush
04-11 10:40:22.113: W/System.err(1524): java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at net.mobile.android.weather.WeatherUpdater$1.onLocationChanged(WeatherUpdater.java:120)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:234)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:167)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:183)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:167)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:183)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-11 10:40:22.117: W/System.err(1524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 10:40:22.132: I/System.out(24325): [INFO:3216487]: LogSource: Running flush
04-11 10:40:22.285: I/System.out(24325): [INFO:3216642]: LogSource: Response [http=200,length=224]
04-11 10:40:22.312: I/System.out(24325): [INFO:3216667]: LogSource: Sending payload [bytes=264]
```